# Open Word in the browser or open a Word file the client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, ms-word

I want to open the Word itself in my program designed with .NET Core in the browser and my user can edit it.
Or in such a way that the user clicks on the option to open the log-in program file, and after making changes and saving, he sits on my server without uploading or downloading.

I don't want to use text editors

Comment: If you don’t want to integrate with OneDrive and Word from Microsoft 365, you will have to write your own web control to emulate, or purchase some commercial ones. Library recommendations are off topic here, and search engines are for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with WebDAV and works with office documents. However authentication can be a challenge without requiring users to install browser extensions/plugins.

https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/ offers a paid solution which has options for several platforms including .NET and solves the authentication problem with a browser extension.

https://github.com/skazantsev/WebDavClient is an open source solution (MIT License) built for .NET Core. I'm not sure how this one approaches the authentication issue.

Comment: The WebDAV user experience is different from opening Word documents in the browser, like Microsoft 365. BTW, WebDAV is an HTTP extension, so normal authentication methods are supported.